# Generic invoicing / billing system for C# or cloud-based with API

Tags: c#, invoicing

We have a system where we want to develop a one-time purchasing option and subscription-based model.  Basically, one would involve purchase one-off document sheets for download.  Users can also subscribe to a 'package', where they can publish an amount of courses online in their member's area.  Hence, the system needs to be able to generate one-time invoices for one-off purchases, as well as yearly invoices for each package.  The system needs to attach to events like when an invoice is paid, so that it performs some custom logic.

I was looking into developing this, but was thinking if there is any C# component or cloud-based system which we can integrate with, which would perform such functionality.  I'm sure this has been done all over again, and I hate re-inventing the wheel.  I've been looking for "invoicing systems", "invoice components", to no avail. It needs to perform the below features:

- Be able to get a list of invoices related to a member, to show them in the member's area
- Reporting on invoices by unpaid, paid, etc
- Ability to know when an invoice is paid, so we can do custom logic related to an invoice
- Integrate with custom payment providers for payment

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: hmm :/ I totally missed the 'Software Recommendations' forum!  Can this be moved, or shall I repost the question there?

Comment: Click the flag button and ask a moderator to move it.